# Response Json from API is not binding to my Model

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, api-design

Im trying to display the `CountryText` from my `Country` model. It seems to pick up the array and displays blank textblocks in the listview but the CountryText does not show.

Im just starting to learn Data Binding so im not sure if im missing something

**XML**

```
<Window x:Class="CovidApi.View.CasesWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CovidApi.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CovidApi.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CasesWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:CasesVM x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
        <Grid>
            <ListView Width="160"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryText}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <ListView Width="160">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
namespace CovidApi.ViewModel
{
    public class CasesVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }

        public CasesVM()
        {
            Countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
        }

        public async void MakeQuery()
{
            var countries = await Covid19Helper.GetLatestAllCountries();

            Countries.Clear();
            foreach (var country in countries)
            {
                Countries.Add(country);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Api Helper**

```
namespace CovidApi.ViewModel.Helpers
{
    public class Covid19Helper
    {
        public static async Task<List<Country>> GetLatestAllCountries()
        {
            List<Country> countries = new();

            string url = "https://covid-19-tracking.p.rapidapi.com/v1";

            using (HttpClient client = new())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-key", "**apiKey**");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-host", "covid-19-tracking.p.rapidapi.com");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(json);
            }

            return countries;
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Country
    {
        public string ActiveCasesText { get; set; }
        public string CountryText { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public string NewCasesText { get; set; }
        public string NewDeathsText { get; set; }
        public string TotalCasesText { get; set; }
        public string TotalDeathsText { get; set; }
        public string TotalRecoveredText { get; set; }
    }
```

[Array showing in left ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywr8h.png)

[Json comes out like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCq71.png)

But the variable that gets deserialized - `countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(json);` shows all properties of Country model as null

Comment: You seem to have included your API key in your sample code. I would advise removing it, especially since you’ve already provided an example API response.

Comment: Ive removed it  but its not a huge deal. Its only a learning tool

Answer (score 1):

A few problems need addressing.

Firstly, simply implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is not enough for data binding to take place. You need to call `OnPropertyChanged(propertyName)` every time you update a property. This is usually done in the getter/setter. (Also, you should not use auto properties if you are doing data binding). Additionally, your `Country` class also needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` too.

I would also recommend using `CallerMemberName` in your `OnPropertyChanged` method. This makes it so you don’t have to include the property name when calling `OnPropertyChanged` - it is instead handled for you during runtime.

Secondly, the JSON deserializer does not know how to populate your `Country` model due to mismatched names. For example, in your model, you have `CountryText`, which I assume should be populated by `Country_text` from the API. You should match the properties in your model with the corresponding JSON name, which is demonstrated in the example below.

So in your example, your country model would have the properties set up like this:

```cs
class YourModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string someProperty;
    [JsonProperty(“<name of this property in your JSON response>”)]
    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get => someProperty;
        set { someProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Your ViewModel would then look something like this:

```cs
class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<YourModel> models;
    public ObservableCollection<YourModel> Models
    {
        get => models;
        set { models = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    // don’t forget to insert your constructor, other properties, 
    // other methods etc somewhere in this class too

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your json properties names are different from c# names, try to map

```
public class Country
{
       [JsonProperty("Active Cases_text ")] 
        public string ActiveCasesText { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Country_text ")] 
        public string CountryText { get; set; }
      .... and so on
}
```

Comment: This is one problem but it isn't enough to fix the data binding, because the OP didn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Country` nor did they call `OnPropertyChanged()` anywhere